# Google App Engine: Share data between users

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to make invitations to share/view data similar to Google Docs?

Comment: Hans, are you confusing google apps and google app engine?

Comment: No, we what to make a web app that can shared data between users in a company (based on gwt and gae). The way google docs allow you to share is great. We would like to do the same thing but find it stupid to program it from scratch, when google has already done it.

Comment: Hans, Google may have already coded similar functionality as a part of  Google Docs, but they have not exposed that API to external applications, and I suspect that it wouldn't be as easy as you might think to integrate into a new application. You are much better off designing and implementing a sharing and permissions model that is tailored to your specific use case.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely: GAE is a platform, a canvas for what you want to build. Document access management is entirely up to you, but of course you'll have access to some APIs to facilitate your life (e.g. Google Accounts integration).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is. You can create virtually any kind of web application that you want with AppEngine. It doesn't come with anything built-in to do this other than an API for sending emails, but you can certainly code up this functionality.